# Which classifier or ML SDK should I use in this case?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib, xgboost

The training data (including both training and validation set) has about `80` million samples and each sample has `200` dense floating points. There are `6` labeled classe and they are imbalanced.

In the common-used ML libs (e.g., `libsvm`, `scikit-learn`, `Spark MLlib`, `random forest`, `XGBoost` or else), which should I use? Regarding the hardware configuration, the machine has `24` CPU cores and `250` Gb memory.

Comment: I would use Spark MLlib

Comment: @DrVComas, thanks! I haven't installed the Spark. If convenient, could you please view this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304536/how-to-scale-a-large-scale-data-in-scikit-learn]?

Comment: That's why I would use spark, if data set is big you can train a model using the entire data set with no problems.

Comment: @DrVComas, yes, now I found the problem is to scale the large scale data. To fit the model, we should first compute the global means and standard deviations. The `map-reduce` is very suitable for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using scikit-learn's [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) as it is online so you can load your training data in chunks (mini-batches) into memory and train the classifier gradually so you won't need to load all the data into memory.

It is highly parallel and easy to use.
You can set the **warm_start** argument to True and call fit multiple times with each chunk of X, y loaded into memory or the better option you can use the partial_fit method.

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', alpha=1e-4, penalty='l2', l1_ratio=0.9, learning_rate='optimal', n_iter=10, shuffle=False, n_jobs=10, fit_intercept=True)
# len(classes) = n_classes
all_classes = np.array(set_of_all_classes)
while True:
    #load a minibatch from disk into memory
    X, y = load_next_chunk()
    clf.partial_fit(X, y, all_classes) 
X_test, y_test = load_test_data()    
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Remember that partial_fit just does just one epoch (loop) over the data so to optimize it better you may need to repeat the whole process say 5 times to converge. Although your data is enough big to give you a good model even by 1 epoch. You should also take care of the order of records. It is better to shuffle the whole 80M records before fitting it into the classifier because if there is a hidden order in the data it may hurt the generalization of the model and so its prediction performance.