# How to scale a large scale data in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

The whole data set has `80` million samples, each sample have `200` dense features. We often train a classifier with batch processing. For example, we adopt the `clf = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`, then we can use `clf.partial_fit(batch_data, batch_y)` to fit the model with the batch data.

Before that, we should first scale the `batch_data`. Suppose we use the `mean-std` normalization. So we should obtain the global mean and standard deviations for each feature dimension. After that, we can use the global mean and stds to scale the batch_data.

Now the problem is how to obtain the mean and std of the whole data set. To compute the global std, we could use $\sigma^2 = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. Then we should compute the `E(X^2)` and `E(X)` by batch processing.

I think the `Hadoop` or `Spark` might be suitable for this task. For each batch of data, we could start a instance to compute the partial `E(X^2)` and `E(X)`, then reduce them into the global ones.

In `scikit-learn`, is there any more efficient way to scale the large data set? Maybe we could use the `multithreading` or start multi processes to handle batch data, then reduce the results to get the global means and stds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `n_jobs` option available in most of the `scikit-learn` algorithms for parallel processing.

For data of this size, I will recommend to use apache spark.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying Spark! Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: There is a relevant article here - [Auto-scaling scikit-learn with Apache Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html)

Comment: Thanks! The reference is very helpful! I'll try that!